# Android map util Cluster double tap

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using google map util v2 to implement marker clustering.

If I click on the cluster, I can detect the click event and perform some operation.

If I double tap the cluster, the map zoom's in. I need to perform some action if the cluster is double tapped but I can't figure it out how to implement.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html

or GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener.html